# How to shift multi-index column without repeating subcolumn names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's say I have a dataframe with a multi-index column:

```
P = pd.DataFrame(
    [[100, 101],
     [101, 102],
     [ 98,  99]],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('price', 'bid'),
         ('price', 'ask')]
    )
)
    
P
```

[image: dataframe]

and I want to add a new column which shows me the data from the previous row:

```
P['price_prev'] = P['price'].shift(1)
```

This throws the error

```
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column price_prev
```

I understand why this happens, and doing

```
P[[('price_prev', 'bid'), ('price_prev', 'ask')]] = P['price'].shift(1)
```

gives me what I want without errors:

[image]

But is there really no way to do this which avoids repeating the names of the subcolumns? I.e., telling pandas to copy the respective column including all of its subcolumns, renaming the top level to whatever was specified, and then shifting all of the data one row down?

Comment: `P['price']` is a dataframe, not a series; you either concatenate or join back to the original dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy: Thanks, knowing that `P['price']` is a dataframe is helpful for understanding the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
P.join(P.shift().rename(lambda x: f'{x}_prev', axis=1, level=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

@ziying35's answer does work, but only if I want to shift my *entire* dataframe.

Here's a similar and slightly less verbose version that also works for individual columns (in this case `price`):

```
P = P.join(P[['price']].shift(), rsuffix='_prev')
```

The one drawback of this compared to the explicit

```
P[[('price_prev', 'bid'), ('price_prev', 'ask')]] = P['price'].shift()
```

is a higher memory usage, so there seems to be a memory leak somewhere when using `join`. However, this might also just be my Jupyter Notebook acting up.